# buildbot http server interface to 0.0.0.0

Tags: twisted, buildbot

I configure Buildbot to create the auto build, and it's working fine.

Just issue is, I am unable to access build admin panel/web UI from another pc.

Buildbot set "127.0.0.1" as HTTP server interface, how can I set the interface to "0.0.0.0", so I can access from any other pc.

Comment: As far as I know buildbot with default network settings is accessible from remote. Are you sure you use correct name or ip and port (8010 by default) of buildbot machine and there are no firewall etc that prevent access?

Comment: I check services using "netstat -ntlp" command, where I found buildbot HTTP service is running on 127.0.0.1:8010, if I want to access it from another pc then it should be :::8010 or 0.0.0.0:8010

Comment: I'm sure it should be `0.0.0.0` by default.


There only place where it could be changed is config file:


    `c['www'] = dict(port="tcp:8010:interface=127.0.0.1",
                plugins=dict(waterfall_view={}, console_view={}))`


If it will not help, please, specify buildbot version and value of `c['www']` in config file